# Dynamically create a TW object in IBM BPM

Tags: javascript, json, object, dynamic, business-process-management

I am using **IBM BPM 8.6**

I have an input string as follows:
`"\"RECORD_CONTACT\":\"Maram\" , \"DRUG\":\"Panadol\"`

In a script on server side, I want to dynamically create a business object like this:

```
tw.local.recordContact = Maram;
tw.local.drug = Panadol;
```

How can I dynamically create the business object?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your request.  The first is that you are not creating a business object, you are creating variables.  In IBM BPM the variables have to be declared at design time or you will get an error, so invoking attempting to call something like -

```
tw.local.myVariable = 'Bob';
```

Will throw an exception if tw.local.myVariable has not been declared.  Base on your other question you asked here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003790/convert-a-json-to-tw-object-of-type-any)), I'm going to assume you actually have an ANY variable declared called "return" so that

```
tw.local.return.myVariable = 'Bob'
```

will work.  Given that I based on Sven's answer I think something like the following will work (you will need to validate)

```
var str = "\"RECORD_CONTACT\":\"Maram\" , \"DRUG\":\"Panadol\"";
var jsonStr = "{" + str.replace(/\\\"/g,'\"') + "}";
var tempValue = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var keyArray = Object.keys(tempValue);
var valueArray = Object.values(tempValue);
for(var keyCount=0; keyCount<keyArray.length; keyCount++{
  var evalString = "tw.local.return."+keyArray[keyCount]+"="+valueArray[keyCount];
  eval(evalString);
}
```

I'll note that doing this is a very bad idea as it would be very brittle code and that using eval() in this manner opens you up to all sorts of possible exploits.  It will also fail badly if the value for one of the keys is not a simple type.

-Andrew Paier

Answer (score 0):

One should know what you are going to do with dynamically created Business Objects (BO) to answer you better. Like a very generic way would be - creating JSON object instead of BO.

But if you want to stick with BO then this is only possible when you know all the BO structure (schema) beforehand during design time.

```
var str = "\"RECORD_CONTACT\":\"Maram\" , \"DRUG\":\"Panadol\"";
vat objArray = str.split("reg ex to split each object string")
foreach (obj in objArray ){
if(obj.indexOf( "RECORD_CONTACT")!=-1)
    tw.local.recordContact = new tw.object.RECORD_CONTACT();
    //below goes code get value of each attribute of BPM from string
}
else if(obj.indexOf( "DRUG")!=-1){
//similar code to create BO DRUG
}
```

Don't forget to create BO before using those :)